# Connections in an Artificial Neural Network

Tags: neural-network

If I have an artificial neural network with any amount of layers and the last (exit) node only accepts 3 inputs (1,x1,x2) what do I do if the hidden layer before has 4 nodes, meaning it creates 4 connections to the last node. Do I just ignore 1? Or do I have to force the last layer to have 3 nodes?

I'm having a hard time dealing with this also with the case if the last hidden layer has only 2 or 1 nodes.

I know this isn't really a programming question but I'm not having a hard time programming this (so far) just dealing with those problems.

So yeah, the idea is that the user can tell me the amount of hidden layers and amount of nodes per layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input which is constant is called *bias*. Assuming you use a typical function for the neuron (sigmoid of weighted sum of the inputs) If one neuron is not connected to the *bias* input, then that neuron can only output 0 if input is 0... Thus you loose the universal function approximation capability of a feed-forward neural network. To avoid that, 2 ways

- neural network got input (x1, x2). Each neuron got its own bias value, thus the neurons compute sigmoid(w1 * x1 + w2 * x2 + ... + wn * xn + bias)
- input is (x1, x2, 1). The neurons simply compute sigmoid(w1 * x1 + w2 * x2 + ... + wn * xn). Each layer is fully connected to the previous one

  ```
  for i in [1, nb_layer - 1]:
    for neuron A in neuron_layer[i]:
      for neuron B in neuron_layer[i+1]:
        connect(A, B)
  ```

I tend to prefer the 2nd solution, as it makes the code and the data more streamlined, no special case, *bias* is seen a special input, a bit like ground voltage for an electric circuit.

Comment: I'm still slightly confused with some things, however your answer helped me get back on track, yeah the 2 approach seems much better.
Thank you